# IIS error in deploying asp.net mvc2

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, iis-7.5, webhttp

I am trying to deploy a wcf webhttp service onto IIS. I am Running Windows 7, IIS 7.5, VS2010.

The Steps 
- Created a project WCF Rest Service Application. 
- Published the project to localhost
- Ensured that the applicationpool was .net 4.0

However, when trying to access the service published at (Default Web Site/HelloRest ) via http://localhost/HelloRest

It gives an error –

**Error Summary** 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

**In the config source** 
modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is highlighted

Is there anything I am missing? When I execute from vs the service works just fine. 
In globals.asax I have -

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("PrintHelloWorld", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(HelloRestService)));
```

When executed from vs2010
http://localhost:59404/PrintHelloWorld/  returns hello world. However, once published

http://localhost/HelloRest/PrintHelloWorld returns the same error as well.

**EDIT**
Figured out the solution. 
- I had installed IIS after installing the .net framework. 
In commandline execute the asp.net registration tool 
- Go to the directory in Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
type aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

Now it starts to work.

Comment: nice catch, you saved me a lot of time. much respect!

Comment: +1 This shouldn't be closed. I had the same *This configuration section cannot be used at this path...* problem today and your `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` solution nailed it. Thanks!

Comment: aspnet_regiis.exe -ir fixed my problem too, was after installing a newer version of IIS after having installed ASP.NET MVC runtime

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert in .Net... But did you try these suggestions?
http://forums.asp.net/t/1220987.aspx